# Python: how to group by for each user?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

```
                      uid                       timestamp          count  val
0   ccf7758a-155f-4ebf-8740-68320f279baa    2020-03-17 13:00:00     23     3
1   ccf7758a-155f-4ebf-8740-68320f279baa    2020-03-17 13:00:00     20     2
2   ccf7758a-155f-4ebf-8740-68320f279baa    2020-03-17 15:00:00     10     5
3   16162f81-d745-41c2-a7d6-f11486958e36    2020-03-18 09:00:00     9      6
4   16162f81-d745-41c2-a7d6-f11486958e36    2020-03-18 09:00:00     9      3
```

I would like to groupby for each `uid` in order to have the sum of `count` every hour and the average of `val`

I would like something like the following

```
                      uid                       timestamp          count  val
0   ccf7758a-155f-4ebf-8740-68320f279baa    2020-03-17 13:00:00     43    2.5
2   ccf7758a-155f-4ebf-8740-68320f279baa    2020-03-17 15:00:00     10     5
3   16162f81-d745-41c2-a7d6-f11486958e36    2020-03-18 09:00:00     18    4.5
```

Comment: try: `df.groupby(['uid', 'timestamp']).agg({'count':'sum', 'val':'mean'})` or `df.groupby(['uid', pd.Grouper(key='timestamp', freq='1H')]).agg({'count':'sum', 'val':'mean'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `groupby` in combination with `agg` using a dictionary style definition of your custom functions:

```
import pandas pd
import numpy as np

df.groupby(['uid', 'timestamp']).agg({"val": np.mean, "count" :np.sum})
```